# PHP MySQL Time Attendance - How to limit Time In (Once a day)

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a Textbox(which is for the Employee ID) and a Time In button that saves the Employee ID, and the current date, and current time(different columns) to the database when clicked. The question is how can I limit the Time in to just once a day.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    require "sampledb.php";

    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Hong_Kong");

    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $time = date('h:i:s');

    if(isset($_POST['in'])){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO timein(empid, date, time) VALUES(".$_POST['eid'].", '$date', '$time')";
        $conn->exec($sql);

        if($sql==true){
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Time in Successful")';
            echo '</script>';
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=sample.php" />';
            }else{
            echo "Time in Failed";
        }
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="">
            <?php echo date("d/m/y : h:i:sa", time()) . "<br>"; ?>
            <input type="text" name="eid" placeholder="Employee ID">
            <input type="submit" name="in" value="Time in">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can mae the date unique with respect to empid in the table timein. So that there will be only one entry for particular empoyee for that particular date

Comment: Let MySQL handle this with a UNIQUE KEY

Comment: But if I set the date to UNIQUE KEY, the new employee ID will not be able to Time IN

Comment: Combine it with employeeID

Answer (score 1):

You can add a **UNIQUE CONSTRAINT** on both the column(empid & date)

Run below query to your table first

```
ALTER TABLE `timein` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`empid `, `date`);
```

The combination of empid and date must be unique.

Answer (score -1):

Before doing your sql insert, do a SELECT statement to see if there is a row for that employee in the required date.
If the num_rows is 0 then proceed to INSERT.
If num_rows is not 0 show error alert message.

Try the below in your php.

```
if(isset($_POST['in'])){
        $eid = $_POST['eid'];
        $sql = "SELECT empid FROM timein WHERE empid='$eid' AND date='$date'";
        $con->exec($sql);
        $count = $con->rowCount();
        if($count == 0){
           $sql = "INSERT INTO timein(empid, date, time) VALUES(".$_POST['eid'].", '$date', '$time')";
           $conn->exec($sql);
 echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Time in Successful")';
            echo '</script>';
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=sample.php" />';
        } else {
            echo "Time in Failed";
        }

    }
```

Comment: This might cause duplicate records in rare cases. (user double clicks, 2 select queries return 0 records, 2 inserts will happen). So a unique key is the solution

Comment: I don't get why the downvote. He can use Post, Redirect, Get method if that's the case. Or disable the button upon the first click.

Comment: Because its only half a solution in my opinion. The database should be responsible for the integrity of your data. Not a (client side) script